# How do you compute $\int_{-1}^{1} \ln(\sinh^2(\ln(x)))dx$ ??

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've created this monster and now I can't solve it properly. I tried integration by parts and inversion, but I didn't get the correct answer based from Wolfram Alpha. I wanna know if there's a small mistake I'm doing or there's something hidden I'm not careful of.

Compute: $$\int_{-1}^{1} \ln(\sinh^2(\ln(x)))dx$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can simplify the expression to

$$I = \int_{-1}^1 \log\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 - \log 4 \:dx = 4\int_0^1 \log\left(\frac{1}{x}-x\right)\:dx - 4\log 2 \equiv 4(J - \log 2)$$

by symmetry. Then evaluating the piece leftover, we obtain

$$J = \int_0^1 \log(1+x) + \log(1-x) - \log(x)\:dx = \int_0^1\log(1+x)\:dx$$

$$ = \int_1^2\log t\:dt = 2\log 2 - 1$$

where the last two terms cancel by symmetry again. Therefore the original integral was

$$I = 4\log 2 - 4$$